# Слово "мусорка"

Tags: жаргон, неологизмы

Последнее время я часто слышу от многих это слово, и это очень огорчает. Привык обходиться словами "помойка" и "урна". Однако, если задуматься, помойкой называют то, что на улице в больших контейнерах, а домашнее ведро так не очень-то назовёшь по-хорошему. Остаётся тогда ведром только и называть, или это слово "мусорка" неизбежно и ему нет никакой замены? Как вы считаете, разве это нормальное слово?

Comment: Очень огорчает? А чем проблема? Вроде слово цензурное. Или вам звучание сочетания звуков м+у+с+о+р+к+а не нравится? (Я правда ни разу не слышал, чтобы ведро так называли - только помойку, но если услышу, меня это не огорчит.)

Comment: Это даже объяснить (себе) сложно почему. Просто интуитивно чувствую, что слово не очень подходящее для нашего языка.

Comment: Да нет. Слово старое. Образовано строго по правилам русского языка: От корня "мусор" + суффикс "ка". Точно также как и "помойка", кстати, где корень от слова "помои", что почти синоним слова "мусор". Видимо в вашем идиолекте оно не употребляется, но это же не значит, что все должны говорить исключительно как вы.

Comment: Разница есть. "Помои" — множественное число без рода, а "мусор" мужского рода.

Comment: И что род и число здесь принципиально меняет?

Comment: Может и ничего не меняют, но чтобы убедить меня в этом, приведите ещё пример с мужским родом.

Comment: Нет никакой причины так считать (что было это слово в ед. ч.). По Вашей логике можно сделать вывод, что были слова "объедок" и "ножница", например.

Comment: Артем, разницы нет. Слово ''помойка'' тем же путем, что и ''мусорка''.

Comment: Если тем же, то мне очень жаль (оно по-прежнему режет слух, не знаю почему). Не знаю, как к нему привыкнуть.

Comment: слово "объедок" и сейчас есть

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не считаю для себя нормальным  (и не употребляю) это слово и слова, образованные таким же способом (молочка, оборонка, нефтянка...). Для некоторых региональных говоров такое словообразование характерно, и оно расширяется вместе с расширением свободы передвижения людей по стране; во многом этому способствует нынешнее отсутствие контроля языковых норм в телевизионной журналистике. Мне особенно неприятно слышать, когда Васильевский остров называют "васькой", а Гостиный двор - "гостинкой". До курьёза доходит, когда переводчики в цитатах из письма времён Второй мировой пишут "пришли мне фотку", а драматурги в пьесе о Первой мировой рассуждают об "откате"; такая же глупость заключена в кинематографическом выражении "завалить Берию" и пр. случаях переноса современных просторечий в исторические сюжеты.

Примером другой бросающейся в глаза тенденции примитивизации языка может служить неумелое использование на публике выражения "в том числе", которое стало заменять выражение "в частности", не требующее упоминания о целом. С него люди в телевизоре умудряются начинать фразу, вставлять его по нескольку раз в одно предложение как междометие и даже отвечать этими словами на вопрос, вместо "да".

Всему своё место. В литературном произведении вполне можно отразить простоватую речь персонажа, много чего ему приписав. В своё время Островский разбросал по пьесам провинциальное просторечие "дорогого стоит", а один спортивный комментатор его упомянул, и оно разошлось. Писатель Войнович ещё в те времена окрестил его "глупым штампом"; я бы сейчас назвал его ещё резче: изысканной пошлостью. Похожая история с хамоватым выражением "чем обязан", мутировавшим из вежливого "чему обязан (удовольствием или счастием)".

Comment: А "помойка" вы используете? Оно ведь тоже таким же способом образовано.

Comment: Да, ***открытка***, ***электричка, безрукавка*** вас тоже раздражают?

Answer (score 2):

> В русском языка начиная с 50-ых годов особенно активным стал т.н. процесс включения (образование новых слов из привычного словосочетания). Напр.: из сочетания прилагательного и существительного (шоссейная дорога) возникает слово - ***шоссейка***. Вместо двух образуется одно. Таких новых слов, полученных посредством включения с помощью суффиксов ***-к(а),-лк(а),*** сегодня уже сотни.  Вот лишь некоторые: ***электричка( электрический поезд), малолитражка (из малолитражная газета), зачетка (из зачетная книжка), прогрессивка (из прогрессивная оплата), зенитка( зенитное оружие), читалка( читательный зал), зажигалка (зажигательная бомба), неотложка (неотложная помощь).*** Все эти слова уже давно вошли в литературный язык. ***С мерно нарастающим гулом проходят вдали электрички( Паустовский. Золотая роза). Движение пригородных электричек  было остановлено ("Известие", 12.05.64г.). Вадим встретился с ним в раздевалке, и они вместе поднялись наверх( Трифонов. Студенты).***
>
> А когда-то против этих слов тоже возражали. Вспомним слово ***открытка*** ( открытое письмо), которое появилось в письменной речи на рубеже XIX - XX вв. и сначала было встречено  ревнителями чистоты языка более чем недружелюбно. Вот что писал в 1922 г.автор книги "Муки слова",лингвист и литературовед А.Г. Горнфельд, признаваясь в собственном вкусовом пуризме: ***"Перед лицом живых явлений как страшно быть доктринером. Лет двадцать пять лет тому назад слово "открытка" казалось мне типичным  и препротивным созданием одесского наречия; теперь его употребляют все, и оно действительно потеряло былой привкус, уличной бойкости" (Новые словечки и старые слова(ПГ., 1922, стр.56).***
>
> Слово ***мусорка*** образовано таким же путем. Это нормальный языковой процесс. Разговорная речь всегда склонна к лаконичности. И хотя это слово не попало еще в официальные толковые словари (В викисловаре оно уже есть), тем не менее, возражать против этого слова нет смысла. Оно широко распространено в нашей речи и возможно скоро будет в словаре.

Comment: _Серж: "возможно скоро будет в словаре."_ ===  См. http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0&all=x

Comment: Да, Слава, в орфографическом словаре я видел.

Comment: Это ж хорошо, что появился новый способ словообразования (хотя этот конкретный способ далеко не новый). Это делает язык гибче. Это гораздо лучше, чем заимствовать из иностранных языков. Ну не может язык оставаться скованным словарями и грамматическими справочниками.

Comment: Конечно! Это очень активный способ словообразования.

Comment: Звучит убедительно, но всё же в данном случае если есть слово "помойка", зачем нужно другое придумывать? В этом и нужды нет в данном случае.

Comment: Все-таки "помойка" и "мусорка'' не синонимы .  Мусорка - разг. 1. контейнер для сбора мусора. 2. разг. площадка для сбора мусора. ПОМОЙКА -Разг. 1. Место сбора помоев и мусора (выброшенных отходов и ненужных вещей и т.п.).

Comment: Синонимом  помойки мусорка может быть только во втором значении.

Comment: К тому же ''мусорка" от слова ''мусор''. Вполне логичное образование.

Answer (score 1):

Нормальное слово, более цивильное, чем помойка. В помойку выливают помои, т.е.из ведра выливают жидкие съестные остатки вместе с мусором(помните в "Собачьем сердце" Шарика помоями облили?), а в мусорку выбрасывают сухой мусор. Растёт культура людей, появляются и соответствующие её уровню слова. Помойки ушли, слава богу, в прошлое, правда , иной раз могут ещё помоями облить, но уже не так часто, как когда-то. Скоро разделять научимся контейнеры: для сухого мусора, для бутылок, для пластика, может, ещё новые слова появятся. Всё закономерно.

Comment: Несмотря на преклонный возраст, ни разу не слышал в своем окружении слово "мусорка" в значении "мусорное ведро" или "урна для мусора", но всегда считал, и не только я, что слово "мусорка" - это разговорно-просторечное от "машина по вывозу мусора"

Comment: Я - про контейнер для мусора, а не про ведро. Ведро- оно и есть ведро, а всякие просторечия.(мусорное ведро=мусорка).. зачем на них внимание обращать? Тётя Глаша какая-нибудь  и не такое скажет...

Answer (score 0):

В данный момент, как я понимаю, слово "мусорка" означает место, куда все граждане организованно приносят из своих жилищ ненужные ТБО (твердые бытовые отходы): упаковки, пластик, металл, бутылки, бумагу, картон, вещи, остатки и очистки еды, непригодные к употреблению, а также стройматериалы.
Другой вопрос, как назвать ведро в квартире, куда всё это собирается, про частный дом не говорю, там всё применимо почти. На мой взгляд, его проще так и называть — ведром под раковиной...

Comment: Хотел посчитать ошибки, но после десяти сбился и теперь лень пересчитывать.